# I can't define layout for Samsung Galaxy Note 2

Tags: android-layout

I have 2 mobile phones: HTC Explorer and Samsung Galaxy Note 2

```
HTC Explorer 
320 x 480 pixels  
3,2"   
180 dpi  
285dp x 426dp

Samsung Galaxy Note 2  
730 x 1280 pixels   
5,5"   
267 dpi  
432dp x 767dp
```

I have a resource folder with name "layout", and when I install my app in HTC, it takes the layout from this folder "layout"

I want that when I install the app in Samsung Galaxy Note 2, it takes the resource from another folder because the screen is bigger and the view is different.

I have called this folder of many types:

```
layout-large  
layout-large-xhdpi  
layout-sw430dp  
layout-sw600dp  
layout-h720dp    
......
```

And *never* takes the layout from this new folder. It *always* takes the layout from "layout" folder, and I lose space. What is the Galaxy Note 2 qualifier?

Could you help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

the problem here is the density of note2... its actually **320** and not **267** and i have verifed it. so you have to make a **layout-sw360dp** folder for note2 because 360dp converted to pixels at 320dpi is **720px** Hope that helps you

Comment: @Avinash Kumar Pankaj any chance you know how to make a layout folder specific for galaxy note

Comment: i would suggest to use fragment

Comment: but if we use this sw360dp - it will affect the S3 and Galaxy Nexus that i have.

Answer (score 0):

`layout-xhdpi` should have worked out try `layout-xxhdpi`